# Apple crash log with multiple dSYMs

Tags: ios, replication, symbolicatecrash

### Briefly:

There are 30 dSYMs I get from iTunes Connect. Which one should I use (they are all named like UUIDs and neither has a human-readable name). All the methods of symbolication I've found require just one (MyApp.app.dSYM), so which one is it?

P.S. The one I take from the archive does not match.

### In details:

My app has been rejected with an issue I was not able to replicate under any circumstances. They say an app crashes upon touching a UITextView field and for some reason imply that the crash happened while connected to an IPv6 network (even though my app does not make any requests at that point (100% sure)).

It had a crash log attached to it too and so I've tried many ways to symbolicate it with no success. The dSYMs archive I download from iTunes Connect has numerous dSYM files, yet none of them is MyApp.app.dSYM. All the tutorials of symbolication I've found mention just ONE dSYM -  "MyApp.app.dSYM". The one I take from the uploaded archive (which does not include downloaded dSYMs, yet includes the "MyApp.app.dSYM") does not help. **The only line it was able to symbolicate was the one in Thread0 (the crashed one) and it pointed to MyClass.swift:49 - the line which does not exist (the file has only 38).**

How do I resolve the given issue? Any help would be much-much appreciated!

Comment: Among the dSYMs you downloaded, is there one with UUID matching the one under the crashing binary image?
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATIONTROUBLESHOOTING

Comment: @xiangxin Yes there is and with help of that tn2151 I've finally managed to symbolicate the only line I could in the crashed thread... The problem is - It says `MyClass.swift:48` yet  there are only *31* line in that file :\